# iphone sdk Localizable.strings files displaying incorrecting in xcode 4.1 after upgrading

Tags: iphone, xcode, editor, utf-16

After upgrading to iphone xcode 4.1 build 4B110F all of my localizable.strings files are showing up as gibberish in the xcode editor.  I created these files using UTF-16.  I can not find a way to tell the editor that they are UTF-16.  I am able to view the Localizable.strings files by viewing as a property list, but if I view them as Source Code, I see gibberish.  I like to translate the entire localization.strings file and paste it into the editor.  I don't want to have to cut and paste one line at a time in the property editor.  There should be some way to tell xcode to show the file as UTF-16.  Does anyone have any ideas?

I tried removing the files and re-adding them.  I used to get prompted for the UTF type, but it does not do this any more.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the text encoding setting for a file in the Utility area of Xcode 4.1. The utility area is the right-handside lateral area.

In the utility area, look for and select the first pane, named "File Inspector".
There, you will find the text encoding in the "Text Settings" block. Expand if necessary using the triangle.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem.  I was able to work around it (without much actual investigation) by simply opening the previous string files in TextWrangler, then copy from TextWrangler and paste into XCode4's view of the string file.    Things seem to be working fine as a result.

Comment: Thanks.  I was thinking that was a possible option.

Answer (score 0):

To fix XCode 4.1 UTF-16 encoding issues:

1: Open the file you want to change
2: Put your cursor into the file, which will give the editor focus (VERY IMPORTANT).
3: Proceed to look under the Utilities Pane (very far right) for Text Settings and use the Text Encoding drop down to select UTF-16 or whatever other encoding you want.

If you forget step 2, and only highlight the file in the Project Navigator, you will not see encoding options.